# Marshalling C++ struct to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I have such simple structure in unmanaged C++:

```
struct Cam
{
    char ip[16];
    char login[16];
    char pass[16];
    char name[16];
};
```

and C# marshalled structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct Cam
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string ip;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string login;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string pass;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string name;
}
```

When I pass C# struct to C++ lib by function

```
[DllImport("NVRLib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void AddCameraStruct(Cam cam);
...
Cam cam = new Cam();
cam.ip = "192.168.0.232";
cam.login = "admin";
cam.pass = "admin";
cam.name = "kekekeke";
AddCameraStruct(cam);
```

and print passed values in C++:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void AddCameraStruct(Camera cam)
{
    printf(cam.ip);
    printf("\n");
    printf(cam.login);
    printf("\n");
    printf(cam.name);
    printf("\n");
    printf(cam.pass);
    strcpy(camera[CAM_NUM].ip, cam.ip);
    strcpy(camera[CAM_NUM].login, cam.login);
    strcpy(camera[CAM_NUM].pass, cam.pass);
    strcpy(camera[CAM_NUM].name, cam.name);
    CAM_NUM++;
}
```

it prints:

```
232
<EMPTY LINE>
192.168.0.232
n
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please add c++ 'Camera' class

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport) __cdecl void AddCameraStruct(Camera cam)`

Comment: @SaniHuttunen If you think that will solve the problem, you should post it as an answer, not as a comment. (I don't think it will, but I could be mistaken.)

Comment: @SaniHuttunen i get error "explicit type is missing" after typing what you wrote

Comment: @JossefHarush look at first listing, there is cam struct in c++

Comment: @hvd: I don't think it will solve the problem but it is better to explicitly declare the calling convention than to let the compiler decide. It will also make it easier for other developers to assess.

Comment: @Lukas I think Jossef Harush's point is that your `AddCameraStruct`'s parameter has type `Camera`, not `Cam`, and `Camera`'s definition is missing from your question. @SaniHuttunen Fair enough.

Comment: @JossefHarush - you were right, I missed that and IDE didn't suggested me nothing because indeed I have also Camera class in c++.. Thank you:)

Comment: Try C++\CLI. You will avoid any implicit declarative marshalling. You will have a .NET assembly with normal .NET class and a method that will instance the C++ structure, fill it from .NET input parameter and call the native function.

Answer (score 2):

After i learned more from your comments,

Change

```
__declspec(dllexport) void AddCameraStruct(Camera cam)
```

To

```
__declspec(dllexport) void AddCameraStruct(Cam cam)
```

Answer (score 2):

Update: you wrote:

> *you were right, I missed that and IDE didn't suggested me nothing because indeed I have also Camera class in c++.. Thank you:)*

which I assumed was a copy and paste error. In the example below it was already corrected like that and it works. Not sure why / if you received errors if your code contained `Cam`, because it is not a recognized structure (in my environment, at least).

Bottom line: the parts of your code that you show, work. You use [`UnmanagedType.ByValTStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor2), which depends on the chosen charset, which you define as [`CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which in turn maps to [`char *`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx) in your DLL library. This is how it should be marshaled, it is simply correct.

I created a test application PInvokeTestDll as follows:

The DLL part, in a Win32 native DLL project:

```
#include <atlbase.h>

WIN32_DLL_UNMANGLED_API void AddCameraStruct(Camera cam)
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    OutputDebugString(A2W(cam.ip));
    OutputDebugString(A2W(cam.login));
    OutputDebugString(A2W(cam.name));
    OutputDebugString(A2W(cam.pass));
}
```

In the header file:

```
#define WIN32_DLL_UNMANGLED_API extern "C" _declspec(dllexport)

struct Camera
{
    char ip[16];
    char login[16];
    char pass[16];
    char name[16];
};

WIN32_DLL_UNMANGLED_API void AddCameraStruct(Camera cam);
```

In the C# project:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
public struct Cam
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string ip;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string login;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string pass;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string name;
}

class Program
{
    [DllImport(@"PInvokeTestDll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void AddCameraStruct(Cam cam);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cam cam = new Cam
        {
            ip = "192.168.0.232", 
            login = "admin", 
            pass = "admin", 
            name = "kekekeke"
        };
        AddCameraStruct(cam);
    }
}
```

Running this project shows the following in the Output > Debug window in Visual Studio:

```
192.168.0.232adminkekekekeadmin
```

As you can see I renamed the `Cam` struct to the `Camera` struct, assuming that was a cut and paste error on your side. I also removed the [`printf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc7014hz.aspx) statements, because you don't see the output during debugging (and the [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires an [`LPCWSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230352.aspx), hence the ATL macro [`A2W`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx)).

My guess is that you are not showing the part that actually causes your structure to fail. I assume it is on the C++ end, because if the structures are what you typed, it "simply works" (this is also "proven" by hovering over the fields of the structure during stepping into the DLL function during debugging). I suggest you isolate the problem by doing what I did: create a test project that only deals with the marshaling and a prototype of the DLL exported function.